# How to make scrollable content within ngBootstrap tooltip without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have basic ngbTooltip taken from official ngbootstrap tooltip website and modified little bit like below
[image]

This looks terrible.To solve this I set `max-height: 100px` and `overflow-y:scroll` `css` attributes but didn't work.As soon as I move mouse cursor from button to tooltip,it disappears.

[image]

As far as I know,there are ways to solve this problem with jQuery but as I'm using angular and ngBootstrap,the way without using jQuery seems more sensible.Is there anyway to solve this problem without jQuery?

Working stackblitz example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhnjwt-yxcbyb?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip.css

Comment: What about using the `[autoClose]="false"` option?

Comment: @user12031119 didn't work.I need tooltip to be shown on hover state not when its clicked